# Error creating custom listview in fragment. Required activity, found fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-listview

I decided to create **custom listview** in my fragment, but I get an error:

> FragmentOne.kt: (41, 53): Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentOne
>   but Activity was expected.

Code below.

**FragmentOne.kt**

```java
class FragmentOne : Fragment() {
    val name = arrayOf(
        "First catch","Second catch","Third catch","Fourth catch"
    )
    val date = arrayOf(
        "01.01.2019", "02.02.2010", "03.03.2003", "04.04.2004"
    )
    val imgId = arrayOf(
        R.drawable.fish
    )
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment




        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen1, container, false)

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val myListAdapter = MyListAdapterInFragment(this,name,date,imgId)
        ListViewInFragment.adapter = myListAdapter

        }
    }
```

**MyListAdapterInFragment.kt**

```java
class MyListAdapterInFragment(private val context: Activity, private val title: Array<String>, private val date: Array<String>, private val imgid: Array<Int>)
    : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_iteminfragment, title) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, view: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val inflater = context.layoutInflater
        val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_iteminfragment, null, true)

        val titleText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.title) as TextView
        val imageView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewInFragment) as ImageView
        val subtitleText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.date) as TextView

        titleText.text = title[position]
        imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position])
        subtitleText.text = date[position]

        return rowView
    }
}
```

Comment: `MyListAdapterInFragment(this,name,date,imgId)` – Change `this` to `activity`.

Comment: don't know why but your code should show error `MyListAdapterInFragment(this,name,date,imgId)` here as you are passing fragment context where activity context is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Fragment Class** does not extend **Context class** in its hierarchy.As a result we can't pass it in place of **context**.

However you can bring **context** inside the fragment by two ways.

1. Using the parent **Activity** on which the **Fragment** is inflated : by typing `activity` in place where `context` is needed.
   -> In your case : 
   `val myListAdapter = MyListAdapterInFragment(activity,name,date,imgId)`
2. Using the *context* from the `inflater` variable which we receive in `onCreateView()` method : by typing `inflater.context`
   -> In your case :
   Make a property `val mContext:Context`.
                assign it the value `mContext = inflater.context` in the onCreateView() method.
   Then use it in your adapter object as
   `val myListAdapter = MyListAdapterInFragment(mContext,name,date,imgId)`

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`val myListAdapter = MyListAdapterInFragment(this,name,date,imgId)`

To this:

`val myListAdapter = MyListAdapterInFragment(activity,name,date,imgId)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `view.context` instead of `this`

```
val myListAdapter = MyListAdapterInFragment(view.context,name,date,imgId)
```